# Which species dance in Tolkien's works?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, races

I know I at least saw the Hobbits dance, but I'm not sure about the others. And if they do dance, what kind of dances do they do (if known, if there isn't much description, ok)? I'm asking about all species, antagonists included.

Comment: Orcs dance in the entrails of their enemies

Comment: @Valorum If _the Hobbit_ were included, you could check off Dwarves, goblins, and (IIRC) Elves.   Probably Bears too. There were probably Men dancing at some of the parties Bilbo had to attend in Lake-Town.

Comment: I include the all the works

Comment: I can't imagine the Ringwraiths dancing. We don't see the Orcs dance, though I'm willing to accept Valorum's comment. I seem to recall Wargs do dance. And yes, Men dance, both at Lake-town and in the Prancing Pony in Bree.

Comment: I changed it to ask which, not just yes or no for all

Comment: Whatever counts. I don't know how that's decided.

Comment: "Species" is the wrong word here, I think.  Elves and humans evidently belong to the same species, as they are completely interfertile.  I don't know what the correct term should be though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Elves (and Bilbo, a Hobbit)**

> And with that he went back to bed and slept till late morning.
> Weariness fell from him soon in that house, and he had many a merry
> jest and dance, early and late, with the elves of the valley [...] and then they went down to the water to see the elves dance and sing upon the midsummer's eve.
>
> <sub><sup>The Hobbit</sup></sub>

**Hobbits**

> When every guest had been welcomed and was finally inside the gate, there were songs, **dances**, music, games, and, of course, food and drink. There were three official meals: lunch, tea, and dinner (or supper). But lunch and tea were marked chiefly by the fact that at those times all the guests were sitting down and eating together. [...] Indeed, in one corner some of the young Tooks and Brandybucks, supposing Uncle Bilbo to have finished (since he had plainly said all that was necessary), now got up an impromptu orchestra, and began a merry dance-tune. Master Everard Took and Miss Melilot Brandybuck got on a table and with bells in their hands began to dance the Springle-ring: a pretty dance, but rather vigorous.
>
> <sup><sub>The Fellowship of the Ring</sub></sup>

**Goblins**

> Smoke was in Bilbo's eyes, he could feel the heat of the flames; and
> through the reek he could see the goblins dancing round and round in a
> circle like people round a midsummer bonfire. Outside the ring of
> dancing warriors with spears and axes stood the wolves at a respectful
> distance, watching and waiting. He could hear the goblins beginning a
> horrible song:
>
> <sub><sup>The Hobbit</sup></sub>

**Bears**

> Most strange of all were the bear-dances. The bears, the black bears especially, had curious dances of their own; but these seem to have become improved and elaborated by the instruction of Men. At times the bears would perform dances for the entertainment of their human friends. The most famous was the Great Bear-dance of Tompollë in the Forostar, to which every year in the autumn many would come from all parts of the island, since it occurred not long after the Eruhantalë, at which a great concourse was assembled. To those not accustomed to the bears the slow (but dignified) motions of the bears, sometimes as many as 50 or more together, appeared astonishing and comic. But it was understood by all admitted to the spectacle that there should be no open laughter. The laughter of Men was a sound that the bears could not understand: it alarmed and angered them.
>
> <sub><sup>The Nature of Middle-earth</sup></sub>

**Lúthien Tinúviel (a Maia)**

> The leaves were long, the grass was green, The hemlock-umbels tall and
> fair, And in the glade a light was seen Of stars in shadow shimmering.
>
> Tinúviel was dancing there to music of a pipe unseen, And light of
> stars was in her hair, and in her raiment glimmering.
>
> <sup><sub>The Fellowship of the Ring</sub></sup>

**Valar**

> There came the Vanyar, and there came the Noldor of Tirion, and the
> Maiar were gathered together, and the Valar were arrayed in their
> beauty and majesty; and they sang before Manwë and Varda in their
> lofty halls, or danced upon the green slopes of the Mountain that
> looked west towards the Trees. [...] And it is sung that in that feast of the Spring of Arda Tulkas espoused Nessa the sister of Oromë, and she danced before the Valar upon the green grass of Almaren.
>
> <sub><sup>The Silmarillion</sup></sub>

**Numenorians**

> The women took little part in these things, though they were generally
> nearer to men than is the case with most races in stature and
> strength, and were agile and fleet of foot in youth. Their great
> delight was in dancing (in which many men also took part) at feasts or
> in leisure time. Many women achieved great fame as dancers, and people
> would go on long journeys to see displays of their art.
>
> <sub><sup>The Nature of Middle-earth</sup></sub>

**Quendi Elves**

> And the ninety-six Quendi now spoke together, and the newly-waked
> devised many new and beautiful words, and many cunning artifices of
> speech; and they laughed, and danced upon the hill-side, until at last
> they desired to find more companions. Then they all set out again
> together, until they came to a lake
>
> <sub><sup>History of Middle-earth Part 11: The legend of the Awaking of the Quendi</sup></sub>

---

And of course, dancing dwarves (well, dwarf)

> 

Comment: Luthien's mother was a Maia, but she's generally considered to be an Elf.

Comment: You have three entries for elves: Elves, Luthien, and Quendi.

Comment: @ibid - Different groups of elves over different time periods

Comment: don't forget Goldberry and Tom Bombadil....whatever they are.

Comment: @NKCampbell - I couldn't find an example of them dancing. I did find lots of examples of them '*[dancing around](https://youtu.be/1p_BvaHsgGg?t=36)'*, which isn't really the same thing, in my opinion.

Comment: @Valorum Nessa is a Vala; I felt it useful to show that ambiguities aside the Vala _do_ dance.

Comment: @Valorum - Then your answer should probably better show that. Or you should perhaps put the general case first, and the specific cases afterwards.

Comment: @ibid Considering the differences among the various branches of the Quendi, it seems relevant to note that dancing was common from the original group across its descended subgroups. (Presumably even the Avari, though we have little textual detail about them.)

Comment: Gimli is described as "capering as he sang loudly in the strange dwarf-tongue" which is arguably dancing, but inelegant

Comment: @alexg - Capering drunkenly isn't dancing, imho

Comment: I suspect drunken capering is the origin of dance.